# enabling joomla sef redirects to absolute resource location

Tags: joomla, sef

I enabled sef in my joomla global configuration, but when i viewed my site it is not displayed and redirects to it absolute address. so now the absolute path is displayed instead of the domain name

Answer (score 1):

Is the .htaccess file correctly named and present at your Joomla root directory?